# Rails internationalization - wrong file is loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, right-to-left, rails-i18n

I added Hebrew to my application, with rtl css logic when locale is `:he`.

Now, even when locale is set to something else, I get translated strings in Hebrew!

I added debugging messages in some places to check locale, and I am convinced it is set to `:en`. I also see the page in ltr format. Still, text is translated to Hebrew!

I tried cleaning browser cache, checked that en.yml exists, and I am blocked.

Comment: check if first line of your hebrew translation file starts with `en:`

Comment: Happens to the best of us. I guess this question will not be of much use to other people so you can close/remove it :)